# Display points from CSV table (feature collection) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, csv, display, feature-collection

Unfortunately, I cannot display the point data I uploaded as csv file. I specified latitude and longitude, the rest is unknown so I kept it at default. Can somebody help?

[Link to asset](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/elenasophier/Validation_data_1999)

Answer (score 1):

When I print your asset to the console, it looks like the latitude/longitude values have not transferred to coordinates. Instead each feature in the collection has properties labeled `latitude` and `longitude` but they both are strings and not numeric data types. The first feature has properties `latitude: 16,474203` and `longitude: 107,564`.

I would guess that this has come up because of the decimal separator in your CSV file. I have not encountered your problem before, but I am US-based and typically use `.` as the decimal for coordinates instead of `,`. Try changing your decimal separator from and re-upload the asset.